# AIR native Android Extension - always returning null device id

Tags: java, android, air-native-extension

I am writing a native Android extension for a mobile AIR application. I am trying to get the device id, but the result always comes back as null. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. Here is the native extension code (java):

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import com.adobe.fre.FREContext;
import com.adobe.fre.FREFunction;
import com.adobe.fre.FREObject;
import com.adobe.fre.FREWrongThreadException;

public class DeviceIdGetter extends Activity implements FREFunction {
    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] passedArgs) {
        FREObject result = null;

        TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        try
        {
            result = FREObject.newObject(tManager.getDeviceId());
        }
        catch (FREWrongThreadException fwte)
        {
            try
            {
                result = FREObject.newObject("error");
            }
            catch (FREWrongThreadException fwte2)
            {
            }
            fwte.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you running this in the emulator?

Comment: No, I am running on my HTC Evo.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using sdk4.6?

The `FREObject.newObject` returns an error `no implementation found for native freobject`, this cause context get `null`.
I think you have copied the `FlashRuntimeExtensions.jar` file from sdks folder to your java project.

Try to add Adobe Flash Builder `4.x\sdks\4.xx\lib\android\FlashRuntimeExtensions.jar` into your jar path.

Comment: I am using 4.6sdk and I am using the file you mentioned..Thanks.

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. All the tutorials I found worked for me months ago, but now with the new SDK and everything I keep getting the null error on the context. Like this answer suggests, I've actually always used an external jar path, and i'm still getting the null error. What's interesting is i'm literally using the same library projects from when i did this in the past, and im still getting the errors. Did Anyone ever find any soltions to this??